# problem on get device information with Gluon

Tags: java, gluon-mobile

I plan to get the IMEI of the phone in order to generate the QR Code or Barcode in my application. I have check the question before asking. More over I also check the gluon mobile docs for more detail. but It seem not solved my problem. The block code inside ispresent() is never ever been execute. Here is my code

```
Services.get(DeviceService.class).ifPresent(deviceService -> {
            label.setText("Modeld: "+"Test" );
            label.setText("Model: "+ deviceService.getModel()+"\nSerial: "+ deviceService.getSerial());
        });
```

Build.gradles

```
  buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'
}
  }

   apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
   jcenter()
   maven {
    url 
 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
}
}

 mainClassName = 'fr.cashmag.GluonApplication'


dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
 }

 jfxmobile {
      downConfig {
    version = '3.8.5'
    // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your 
project context menu instead
    plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
  }
android {
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
ios {
    infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    forceLinkClasses = [
            'fr.cashmag.**.*',
            'com.gluonhq.**.*',
            'javax.annotations.**.*',
            'javax.inject.**.*',
            'javax.json.**.*',
            'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
    ]
}
}
```

The application doesn't seem to show any error in the logcat when I deploy it the the real devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the `downConfig` block on your build file, you will notice the list of plugins, or Charm Down services, your app is using:

```
jfxmobile {
     downConfig {
        version = '3.8.5'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
     }
...
}
```

The `jfxmobile` is adding for you for each of those plugins the core artifact and their platform implementations:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'

    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-display:3.8.5'
    desktopCompile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-display-desktop:3.8.5'
    androidCompile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-display-android:3.8.5'
    iosCompile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-display-ios:3.8.5'
    ...
}
```

Because you also have `charm`, it has transitive dependencies in some other services, like `device`, but only in the core artifact, so you will be adding:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-device:3.8.5'
    ...
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-display:3.8.5'
    desktopCompile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-display-desktop:3.8.5'
    androidCompile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-display-android:3.8.5'
    iosCompile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-display-ios:3.8.5'
    ...
}
```

And this is why your project can use `DeviceService`.

But you are not adding the platform implementation of that service. So when you run on any platform `Services.get(DeviceService.class).get()` will be null.

In this case, all you need to do is add the `device` plugin to the list:

[image: device plugin]

Your build will have:

```
jfxmobile {
     downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        plugins 'device', 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
     }
...
}
```

Note that you can use Charm Down `3.8.6` now.

Comment: Now, How to get IMEI? It seem that we don't have that option

Comment: That is discouraged. Apple doesn't allow it. DeviceService provides an `UUID` [parameter](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/DeviceService.html#getUuid--), that is good enough for having a single identifier.